# How do I stop Facebook from presenting me with a CAPTCHA?

Tags: facebook-pages, verification, captcha

How do I avoid getting presented with a CAPTCHA each time?

[image: CAPTCHA example]

Comment: What are you trying to do when this appears?

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove the security codes (CAPTCHAs) from your Facebook page.